# Align an SVG icon next to a span, same vertical

Tags: css, tailwind-css

```
<div class="flex items-center">
  <span class="inline-flex items-center px-2.5 py-0.5 rounded-full text-xs font-medium bg-red-100 text-red-800 mb-5">
    Recommended
  </span>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="w-5 h-5 ml-2">
    <path fill="red" d="M15.362 5.214A8.252 8.252 0 0112 21 8.25 8.25 0 016.038 7.048 8.287 8.287 0 009 9.6a8.983 8.983 0 013.361-6.867 8.21 8.21 0 003 2.48z" />
    <path fill="yellow" d="M12 18a3.75 3.75 0 00.495-7.467 5.99 5.99 0 00-1.925 3.546 5.974 5.974 0 01-2.133-1A3.75 3.75 0 0012 18z" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/CTtHNhvQQW

Why is there such a gap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you gave the recommended button a bottom margin. Remove the `mb-5` (margin-bottom: 1.25rem;)

https://play.tailwindcss.com/OAdKgxMnLY